# How to write tif file in java from another tif file using GeoTIFF?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, jai

I am looking for reading tiff file then processing its pixels and write it back again as a tiff file. Is it possilbe, if yes please provide some 5-10 line sample.

```
ParameterValue<OverviewPolicy> policy = AbstractGridFormat.OVERVIEW_POLICY
        .createValue();
policy.setValue(OverviewPolicy.IGNORE);

// this will basically read 4 tiles worth of data at once from the disk...
ParameterValue<String> gridsize = AbstractGridFormat.SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE.createValue();
//gridsize.setValue(512 * 4 + "," + 512);

// Setting read type: use JAI ImageRead (true) or ImageReaders read methods (false)
ParameterValue<Boolean> useJaiRead = AbstractGridFormat.USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD.createValue();
useJaiRead.setValue(true);

//reader.read(new GeneralParameterValue[] { policy, gridsize, useJaiRead });
GridCoverage2D image
        = new GeoTiffReader(f).read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});
Rectangle2D bounds2D = image.getEnvelope2D().getBounds2D();
bounds2D.getCenterX();
// calculate zoom level for the image
GridGeometry2D geometry = image.getGridGeometry();



BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
```

Here I got bufferedimage which i will process for some functions then

I would like to write this tiff again as a new file and I will process it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a [GridCoverageFactory](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/GridCoverageFactory.html) to create a new GridCoverage and a [GridCoverageWriter](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/coverage/grid/GridCoverageWriter.html) to write it to disk:

```
File in = new File(inFile);
AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(in);

AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(in);

GridCoverage2D cov = null;
try {
  cov = reader.read(null);
} catch (IOException giveUp) {
  throw new RuntimeException(giveUp);
}
reader.dispose();
RenderedImage rImage = cov.getRenderedImage();
RenderedImage outImage = ScaleRaster.scale(rImage, 0.5f);
File out = new File(outFile);
GridCoverageWriter writer = format.getWriter(out);
GridCoverageFactory factory = new GridCoverageFactory();
GridCoverage outCov =  factory.create("name", outImage, cov.getEnvelope());
writer.write(outCov , null);
writer.dispose();
```